# What do you call the protruding backside of a car?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call the protruding backside of a car?

I am referring to the part behind the seats and the black cover of the car in this picture. Is there a particular name for it?

Comment: There are a lot of parts behind the seats and black cover: The rear wheelwell, the license plate, the trunk, to spoiler, the back bumper, the tailpipe, and the taillights. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Personally, I don't think it could be more specific. What protrudes in a sedan is the back end of the car, isn't it?

Comment: Seems like OP is actually asking about the "shelf" behind the heads of backseat passengers that is under the back windows and inside the passenger compartment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're talking about the **trunk** (*American English*). The back part where you put stuff in such as luggage. [image]

Just a quick tip for next time, if you go on Google and select "images" and then write "**Car parts names in English**" you will see a bunch of car parts with names from ESL websites.

Comment: The 'boot' in British English.

Comment: Well, the trunk/boot is a very specific part of the rear of the car. It's not the whole thing. I would simply call it "the rear."

Comment: Or the **rear end**.

Comment: @Robusto  I think it's fair to call it the *trunk/boot* either way, as this is standard, even though it can be confusing when the *actual* trunk is in the front.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think "rear end" refers to the area behind the trunk, where the taillights are located. I don't think it refers to the entire section of the car behind the passenger compartment.

Comment: While the rear end of a car is traditionally a *trunk*, technically in OP's picture, the trunk is in the *front* of the car. (Porsches have their engine in the rear) ...but colloquially I'm sure you can still call that part the trunk and nobody would really be confused.  (See @fluffysheap's answer for a little more on that).

Answer (score 7):

There is no formal term for this.

"Trunk" (or "boot") is probably what most people would say, but the term only actually refers to the actual baggage compartment and not the region of the car.  The particular car in your example is a Porsche Boxster, which has the baggage compartment in the front, and the engine in the back.  Even Porsche owners [don't know](http://forums.pelicanparts.com/porsche-911-technical-forum/711948-stupid-question-hood-trunk.html) what words to use.

In practice, people will generally understand "trunk"/"boot" to mean what you intend, but it is not technically correct.  "Rear" is probably the most correct.

Answer (score 1):

The front end of a car
The read end of a car

Here is the front end of new Ford Focus:

[image: front end of the Ford Focus]

Rear end of a Mercedes:

[image: read end]

I think front end and rear end are generic enough to include the entire portion of a car from the front windows forward and the back windows back (on a sedan for instance).

For me, this is not about trunks and boots, for sedans.

These pictures function as free advertising for these vehicles as they contain the brand names.